# Javascript for split the string and loop to get to character

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, split

I have a string something like the below one which gets populated into a text field after looping through the grid from grid one ,1 | xxx,2 | yyy,3 | zzz,4| ,5 |

it is model, Index | Model, index | .... where if nothing is there its blank.
Now I want logic to get only model and check that against index value and set the model in another grid 2 cell values.

Below is my current code which is very lengthy:

```
test() {
    alert(Moment);
    var totalSize = fieldname.getGridSize();
    //var getModel =       fieldname.getValue();
    var getModel = document.getElementById("Desktfieldname").value;


    if (getModel && getModel != '') {

        var res = getModel.split("|");
        alert(res);
        var model1 = res[0];
        var model2 = res[1];
        var model3 = res[2];
        var model4 = res[3];
        var model5 = res[4];

        if (model1 != '') {
            var res1 = model1.split(",");
            alert(res1);
            var modelfinal1 = res1[0];
            var indexfinal1 = res1[1];
        }

        if (model2 != '') {
            var res2 = model2.split(",");
            alert(res2);
            var modelfinal2 = res2[0];
            var indexfinal2 = res2[1];
        }


        if (model3 != '') {
            var res3 = model3.split(",");
            alert(res3);
            var modelfinal3 = res3[0];
            var indexfinal3 = res3[1];
        }

        if (model4 != '') {
            var res4 = model4.split(",")
            var modelfinal4 = res4[0];
            var indexfinal4 = res4[1];
        }

        if (model5 != '') {
            var res5 = model5.split(",")
            var modelfinal5 = res5[0];
            var indexfinal5 = res5[1];

            for (var s = 1; s <= totalSize; s++) {
                var cellValIndex = Index.getCellValue(s);
                alert(cellValIndex);
                alert(modelfinal1);
                if (cellValIndex && cellValIndex != '') {
                    if (cellValIndex == modelfinal1) {
                        expr = 'feildName.setCellValue         (' + s + ",'" + indexfinal1 + "')";
                        eval(expr);
                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, i believe you should keep your `for` loop outside of the `if` condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear, not sure what exactly you are trying to get as end result

However, maybe this helps:

you can split your string into array and then access it with index

```
var modelIndexes = string.split('|');
```

after that you can access any of your modules with array index (use for loop or whatever you need in your case) and split it again to get what you need from it

```
var modelInstance = modelIndexes[i].split(',');
var index = modelInstance[0]; // contains your model
var model = modelInstance[1]; // contains your index
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a object is a better model for what you are trying to accomplish, but if this has to be done with a string you can use RegExp to parse the matches in the string:

```js
var myString = "one,1 | xxx,2 | yyy,3 | zzz,4| ,5 |";
var regEx = new RegExp(/\w*,\d/g);

var myArray;
while ((myArray = regEx.exec(myString)) !== null) {
  var cell = myArray[0].split(',');
  var msg = 'Found ' + cell.join(',') + '.  Value: \'' + cell[0] + '\'. Index: ' + cell[1];
  console.log(msg);
}
```